# return an object without a specific value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

i've got an object like:

```
Obj = {
  foo: false,
  bar: true,
  private: {
    something: 'else'
  }
}
```

now i want to return this object without the private part! I cannot splice it, because it is used, just not needed somewhere else. For some reason i can't find a solution.

I can use Underscore.js and am working on node.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what [`omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) is for:

```
var public = _.omit(Obj, 'private'); // {foo: false, bar: true}
```

Comment: perfect! Don't know why i missed that one!

Comment: Do you also know a quick way to use this is the Obj was an item of an Array? Returning mulitple Objs without private

Comment: Probably just use `map`, `arr.map(function(x) { return _.omit(x, 'private'); })`

Answer (score 2):

Pure javascript solution :

```
var copy = {};
for (var k in Obj) copy[k] = Obj[k];
delete copy.private;
```

With an array of "`Obj`" called "`array`" :

```
var i = 0,
    arrayCopy = [],
    itemCopy,
    item;

while (i < array.length) {
    item = array[i++];
    itemCopy = {};
    for (var k in item) itemCopy[k] = item[k];
    delete itemCopy.private;
    arrayCopy.push(itemCopy);
}
```